# SUM on a data.frame returns error

Tags: r

I have a data.frame named PSIBL_out.

```
   sallgi     stext2    staxid           stext3  
1   hgd;te;     hgh     gfg;dgj;jhh       AJJC
2   hf          jhd     hjhj              hgfd
3   oui         dhk     kjll              jhjs
```

I want to find all rows in which the column "staxids" has multiple values, separated by ";". For each such row, I want to look in the the "sallgi" column, count how many times the ";" appears and put the number in "a".

```
The code I wrote is the following:

  for(i in PSIBl_out[grep(";", PSIBl_out[,"staxids"]),])
  {
   a <- sum(PSIBl_out[grep(";", PSIBl_out[,"sallgi"]),])
  }
```

I get the following error, which I believe is for the SUM function:

```
 Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : 
  only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables
```

Ideas?

Comment: I think your problem is that you're using `grep` rather than `grepl`. Be sure to read the docs on those carefully to see what each returns.

Comment: ...and you're trying to sum a data frame, which makes no sense. To count, you apply sum to the output of `grepl`.

Comment: yes, you're right, I apply sum i the wrong way

Comment: another mistake I realized is how I'm using grep

Comment: I'm trying now the following:    for(i in PSIBl_out[grep(";", PSIBl_out[,"staxids"]),])
  {
   a <- str_count(PSIBl_out[i,"sallgi"], ";")

Comment: doesn't look successful either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is still a bit unclear (and by the way, you should clarify your question by *editing* it, not leaving comments!).

But I'm guessing you want something like this:

```
library(stringr)
> dat <- read.table(text = "sallgi     stext2    staxid           stext3  
+ 1   hgd;te;     hgh     gfg;dgj;jhh       AJJC
+ 2   hf          jhd     hjhj              hgfd
+ 3   oui         dhk     kjll              jhjs",header = TRUE,sep = "")
> str_count(dat$sallgi[grepl(";",dat$staxid)],";")
[1] 2
```

But it is not clear from your question whether you want a count for each row in your original data frame, or just for those rows with `;` present in the `staxid` column.

Comment: Thanks for the tip with editing, I was looking for something like this, but haven't seen it till you pointed out. And yes, I want to count only for those rows returned from applying grep on the staxid column